# Windows 10 + Ubuntu 15.10 Dual boot perfect BUT Ubuntu needs 10MINUTES to Start up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

In my desktop HP Pavilion 20 I got Windows 10 updating the previous Windows 8.
I installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10.
If I select Windows, the Start up time is always regular.
If I choose Ubuntu, the Start up time is 10-15 Minutes, sometime it freezes up and I must shut down and turn on the machine.
Any suggestion to avoid this problem?
Thanks. Ruggero.

Comment: What filesystem does your Ubuntu system use?

Answer (score 1):

### Fast-Startup & Hibernation

If you have set the Windows partition to be automatically mounted (check in /etc/fstab if that's true), then having Windows hibernated is probably to blame.

If you didn't hibernate Windows before switching over to Ubuntu, then the problem is most likely due to Windows' fast-startup option where it partially hibernates the OS when shutting down.

To be able to avoid it, use restart instead of shutdown when you want to switch over, or turn off fast-startup.

**Turning fast-startup off or on from control panel (long way):**

1. Open the Control Panel, and click on the Power Options.
2. Click/tap on the click the `What the power buttons do` link on the left side.
3. Click/tap on the `Change settings that are currently unavailable` link at the top.
4. If prompted by UAC, click/tap on Yes.
5. Do step 6 or step 7 below for what you would like to do.
6. To Turn On Fast Startup (this is the default setting).

   A) Under Shutdown settings, check the Turn on fast startup box, click/tap on the Save changes button, and go to step 8 below. (see screenshot below step 8)
7. To Turn Off Fast Startup

   A) Under Shutdown settings, uncheck the Turn on fast startup box, click/tap on the Save changes button, and go to step 8 below. (see screenshot below step 8)
8. You can now close the System Settings window if you like.
   Note
   If the Turn on fast startup setting is not listed, then you will need to close the System Settings window, enable hibernate, then start over at step 1 again.

**To turn on/off fast startup using a BAT file (fast way):**

*The .bat files below will change the registry key and value below.*

Open the `run` program with the (Can use the Windows + R shortcut). Open regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power
```

Change the DWORD value for the DWHiberbootEnabled entry.

*0 = Turn off fast startup
1 = Turn on fast startup*

Download and run the .bat file as admin:

[Disable fast-startup](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/12686d1424036052-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a-turn_off_fast_startup.bat)

If ever want to turn it back on use: 
[Enable fast-startup](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/12687d1424036052-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a-turn_on_fast_startup.bat)

References: [*1*](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html), [*2*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8/)

---

### Check your drives for errors

Here's two ways of doing so:

**When starting up your computer**

On the grub boot loader, pick `Advanced options for Ubuntu 15.10`, then pick an option `(recovery options)`.

Next go down to `fsck    Check all file systems` and press enter. It warn you that it will remount that it'll remount your drives in read/write mode instead of staying in read-only mode, so it can apply changes if needed.

**When you're on a live cd/usb/sdcard session**

You can run:

```
sudo fsck -CV /dev/sda
```

*`-C` Display completion/progress bars for those  filesystem  checkers*
*`-V` Produces verbose output, including all file-system specific commands that are executed.*

The reason why I stated to do this on a live cd/usb session because it's **not** recommended to do this on a running system; doing so **WILL**
cause **SEVERE** filesystem damage if the filesystems being checked are still mounted.

References: [1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/fsck.8.html)